# Getting the error in terraform code while trying to connect to linux server in OCI cloud shell . ------Failed to read ssh private key: no key found

Tags: terraform, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, terraform-provider-oci, oracle-cloud-shell

Getting the  error in terraform code  while trying to connect to linux server in OCI cloud shell . ------Failed to read ssh private key: no key found
Below is my code  : -

```
resource "null_resource" "remote-exec" {
        
    
    provisioner "remote-exec" {
        connection {
            agent = false
            timeout = "10m"
            host ="xx.xx.x.x" 
            user = var.host_user_name
            private_key =file("${path.module}/integerebspvtkey.ssh.ppk")
        }
        inline = [
            ...
        ]
    }
    }



    variable "host_user_name"{
          default="opc"
    }
```

integerebspvtkey.ssh.ppk is the private key present in the same directory from where I am running the terraform

Comment: Are you sure it should be in `ppk` formatat, not `pem`?

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot . i converted it to pem format , not getting this error now. But got stuck into another issue `null_resource.remote-exec: Still creating... [1m50s elapsed]` . getting timeout error while doing ssh

Comment: No problem. I would suggest making new question for the new issue with timeout. Also acceptance of my answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was **wrong format** of the key. Instead of `ppk`, it should be `pem`.